# Creating a find dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

So for this assignment in class I'm making a richtextbox editor in C# winforms, in this assignment I have to include a find function, but I can't seem to get the hang of it
EDIT: it closes every time I click the search button, but that's not what I want, I want it to close when the user closes the actual dialog via the X in the top right, the search button should just highlight the found string by using the .Find() method

Here's my code up until now:

```
private void zoekenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchValue = SearchDialog();
    Search(searchValue);
}

public string SearchDialog()
{
    Form findDialog = new Form();
    findDialog.Width = 500;
    findDialog.Height = 142;
    findDialog.Text = "Zoeken";
    Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 10, Top = 20, Text = "Zoek naar:", Width = 100 };
    TextBox inputBox = new TextBox() { Left = 150, Top = 20, Width = 300};
    Button search = new Button() { Text = "Zoek", Left = 350, Width = 100, Top = 70 };
    search.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { findDialog.Close(); };
    findDialog.Controls.Add(search);
    findDialog.Controls.Add(textLabel);
    findDialog.Controls.Add(inputBox);
    findDialog.ShowDialog();
    return (string)inputBox.Text;
}

void Search(string searchValue)
{
    rtxtInhoud.Find(searchValue);
}
```

The part: 
    `search.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { findDialog.Close(); };`
is what I'm really stuck on
Thanks in advance

EDIT: here's something that I tried to do, which didn't work

```
public string SearchDialog()
{
   Form findDialog = new Form();
   findDialog.Width = 500;
   findDialog.Height = 142;
   findDialog.Text = "Zoeken";
   Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 10, Top = 20, Text = "Zoek naar:", Width = 100 };
   TextBox inputBox = new TextBox() { Left = 150, Top = 20, Width = 300};
   Button search = new Button() { Text = "Zoek", Left = 350, Width = 100, Top = 70 };
   Button findNext = new Button() { Text = "Volgende", Left 250, Width = 100, Top = 70};
   search.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { rtxtInhoud.Find(inputBox.Text); };
   findDialog.Controls.Add(search);
   findDialog.Controls.Add(textLabel);
   findDialog.Controls.Add(inputBox);
   findDialog.ShowDialog();
   return (string)inputBox.Text;
}
```

This waits for the Dialog to be closed before highlighting the found string. Which is NOT what I want, I want it to keep the Dialog open, but still highlight the text

Comment: There's no question here. Please explain exactly what you are having issues with.

Comment: Your code seems fine to me: it launches a dialog and returns the text input by the user. What part are you stuck on?

Comment: Can we assume that the first code block is `SearchDialog`'s method body? It would take only little extra effort on your part to make this explicit so that people would not have to guess.

Comment: I've edited the code & explanation @RufusL

Comment: In your code above, you are explicitly calling `findDialog.Close()` in your `search.Click` event handler. Put the code there that you want to execute when they click "search".

Comment: When you say the search button should "highlight the found string", what are you talking about? The user enters a string in the text box. Then what are you searching??

Comment: the user enters a string in the text box, which I then return to my function in which I search for that particular string in the entire text by using the .find() method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your main form code, create a method that searches your text and highlights a found string. Then hook this method up to your search dialog button like the sample below. Also, I think you should call `form.Show()` instead of `.ShowDialog()`, so the other form can respond to input.

```
private void HighlightString(string stringToHighlight)
{
    // Code here to search your text and highlight a string.
}

private void SearchDialog()
{
    var findDialog = new Form {Width = 500, Height = 142, Text = "Zoeken"};
    var textLabel = new Label() {Left = 10, Top = 20, Text = "Zoek naar:", Width = 100};
    var inputBox = new TextBox() {Left = 150, Top = 20, Width = 300};
    var search = new Button() {Text = "Zoek", Left = 350, Width = 100, Top = 70};

    search.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => HighlightString(inputBox.Text);

    findDialog.Controls.Add(search);
    findDialog.Controls.Add(textLabel);
    findDialog.Controls.Add(inputBox);
    findDialog.Show();
}
```

Comment: what would be used to check if .Find has a found a match, thinking I should use .Find() here. Again, I'm a beginner to this, I'm still in school @RufusL

Comment: Questions on this site need to be specific and granular. I thought your question was about how to call the `HighlightString` method from your search button without closing the search dialog? Implementing the `HighlightString` method is a different question... If this solves your original question, please mark as answered and ask a new one!

Comment: Thanks...let me know if you get stuck with the Find implementation

Answer (score 0):

> it closes every time I click the search button

Yes, that's because you added an event handler to the search button that closes the form:

```
search.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { findDialog.Close(); };
```

> but that's not what I want, I want it to [...]

Then write the code in that handler such that it does what you actually want it to do, instead of having it close the form.

Comment: @MikeDonkers We given that you haven't described what you want to do, we can't possibly help you with that.

Comment: EDIT: it closes every time I click the search button, but that's not what I want, I want it to close when the user closes the actual dialog via the X in the top right, the search button should just highlight the found string by using the .Find() method

Comment: That's what I wrote, doesn't that explain it? because I've tried to write the code in the handler differently, but I couldn't make it happen

Comment: @MikeDonkers Then don't tell the search button to close the dialog.  If that's not what you want it to do, then don't tell it to do that.  If you know what it should do, then have the handler do what you *actually* want it to do.  Apparently you do know what you want it to do, so write *that* instead.

Comment: That's what I've tried as earlier mentioned, but I couldn't make it happen. Which is why I posted this question here

Comment: @MikeDonkers So you thought that calling "close" on the form was the proper way to highlight text in the textbox?  Really?  If you actually tried to highlight the text in the textbox then show us what you tried, and explain why it isn't working.

Comment: What would you use when doing this? I'm really stuck on this part, as mentioned in the question, I'm still in school for this @Servy

Comment: @MikeDonkers Again, what did you try that isn't working, and why isn't it working?

Comment: I've tried calling the .Find() method directly in that handler, that didn't work because somehow, the code I've written waits for the dialog to be closed, before highlighting the text @Servy

Comment: @MikeDonkers If you're calling `Find` in the handler then why is the code in your question calling `Close`?  Again, you haven't showed us what you're doing.  We can't tell you why the code you haven't showed us isn't doing what you want.  I've answered the question that you actually asked.  I cannot answer questions that you have that you haven't actually asked, or provided sufficient information to answer.

Comment: I've put another piece of code in the question with the .Find() method in the handler, which waits for the dialog to close before highlighting the found string

Comment: @MikeDonkers That code is still calling the form's `Close` method in the handler.  In fact, it's literally *exactly* the same code.

Comment: @MikeDonkers That is not a reproducible example.  As shown, the code will run when you click the button, no later.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
Application.Exit();
```